# Nodejs wifi scan only return current WiFi on Azure WebApp

Tags: node.js, azure, netsh

I've a nodejs app using this npm package (https://github.com/ancasicolica/node-wifi-scanner ) which basically use netsh wlan command to list all surrounding wifi.  when I run this locally, everything fine but when /I deploy this to Azure Web App, it will only return the connected WiFi but bit surrounding.  Any idea of what might have been wrong on Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Technical background](https://github.com/ancasicolica/node-wifi-scanner#technical-background) describes:

> The module uses command line tools for gathering the network information:
>    netsh on Windows: `netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid`

And we do not have sufficient permission to run this command on Azure Web Apps.

And secondly, As @astaykov said, Azure is a cloud compute platform, all the services and resources are in the Azure Data Centers, which cannot detect your WiFi environment on your local.

You cannot approach your requirement on any cloud compute platforms. You need to to the detection operations on your client side or devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong on Azure!

Do you really expect to scan for WiFi networks inside an Azure Data Center (the chance that there is a WiFi network inside Azure Data Center is close zero) ?!

Do you believe that servers running inside Azure Data Center do have WiFi adapters (I don't) ?!

And what exactly are you trying to achieve - a server based application running on server somewhere on Internet, using netsch on the server to scan for WiFi networks available on your laptop? No, this is not possible. And this is not Azure limitation, and has nothing to do with Azure.

Comment: Thanks both as I'm new to nodejs and I mistaken this npm package is run on client side.   As I'm actually writing a bot (nodejs) using botframework and the purpose of using that wifi-scan npm package is for the bot able to determine the user geo-location to provide relevant service near them.

Comment: Would you kind enough point me a direction on how to use this node-wifi-scan npm package run on client side as I make a search on internet and can't find anything.

Comment: @WilliamTam, you do not need to scan WiFi SSIDs to gets user Geo Location. At least I am not aware of a method to detect geo location based on available WiFi SSIDs. You can, however use user IP address and do best guess on user location by searching in some GeoIP Database like: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ or https://db-ip.com/db/ or use some similar service.